# How to Convert RxJava (Single firstOrError() ) to Kotlin Flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have Observable on which i apply `firstOrError()` operator which return a `Single<T>`
Same i want to convert into Kotlin Flow. I want there must be some mechanism which return a flow with 1st item or error.
Do you have any idea on this how i can achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

To convert `Observable` into `Flow`, you can use [asFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.rx2/as-flow.html) from [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)library.

Note that there is no way to convert `Single` into `Flow` because those are two incompatible types (single-value vs stream). But you can convert your `Observable` into `Flow` with `asFlow` first and then instead of `firstOrError()` use `first()`.

Comment: But then we will not get Error if any ?

Comment: It should work the same as Rx's firstOrError, it's just not part of the name :)
"The terminal operator that returns the first element emitted by the flow and then cancels flow's collection. Throws NoSuchElementException if the flow was empty."